# Python function didn't pass in, openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

At first my function called display_lines passed a line parameters from my HoughLinesP array and then i tried to created a average line to smooth the lines, but it didn't pass in on my display_lines function, i tried to print it inside the function it only showed the HoughLinesP array instead of my average line

this is the function for make_coordinates

```
def make_coordinates(image, line_parameters):
    slope, intercept = line_parameters
    y1 = image.shape[0] 
    y2 = int(y1*(3/5)) 
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept)/slope)
    return np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2])
```

this is the function to find the average of the line

```
def average_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit = [] 
    right_fit = []
    for line in lines:  
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        parameters = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        slope = parameters[0]
        intercept = parameters[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    left_line = make_coordinates(image, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_coordinates(image, right_fit_average)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])
```

this is the HoughLineP, averaged_line and line_image

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(lane_image, lines)
line_image = display_lines(lane_image, averaged_lines)
```

This is the result when i print lines and averaged_lines

- [print(lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SW2T.png)
- [print(averaged_lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx5iE.png)

Comment: fix your indentations

Comment: Please, don't post images of text. Beside that, I'm not sure what's the problem. If I retype all the line parameters, run your code and display all the lines, the results seem quite reasonable.